# split a pandas column based on value proportion from the total

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a list from a bigger list based on the contribution of each row to the total. 
I want the list to include the "top"rows that contribute to 40% of the total

Each row corresponds to a percentage of a total. For example, the first list must includes the rows which cumulative total contributes to 40% of the "total". the "total" there is the sum of all the rows in the column.

```
list = [0.2, 0.25, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05]
```

and I would like to get:

```
list1 = [0.2, 0.25, 0.15, 0.1]
```

because the values in list 1 are the biggest values in the list and they are the one that contributes to make 40% of the list.

How can I write python code to do that?

I have no idea of how to proceed, everything resource that I have looked at teaches how to split based on fixed values but I have seen nothing about classification based contribution percentage of the sum of the values in the list.

I was wondering if anybody had an idea on what function i could use, or how I could proceed. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have a DataFrame or a Series?

Comment: I am working with a DataFrame, i wrote a list here to illustrate my issue in a simple manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import math

list0

# Out[75]: [0.2, 0.25, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05]

list1 = sorted(list0)[-(math.ceil(len(list0)*0.4)):]

list1

# Out[79]: [0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25]
```